# Add a new column to Pandas DataFrame with coding data from a separate DataFrame without using a Loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

The problem I have is that I have a large dataframe (~300,000 rows) with multiple rows for each subject representing the given value under different conditions.  A simplified version is shown below:

```
In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
   SubID  Condition  Value
0      1          1  0.123
1      1          2  0.234
2      2          1  0.345
3      2          2  0.456
4      3          1  0.567
5      3          2  0.678
6      4          1  0.789
```

I also have a second table with only 80 odd rows that holds the genetic group that the subject belongs to.

I wish to add that data to the first DataFrame.  A simplified version of the coding table is shown below:

```
In [17]: df2
Out[17]:
   Subject Number Genetic Group
0               1             A
1               2             C
2               3             A
3               4             B
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
In [19]: df1
Out[19]:
   SubID  Condition  Value Genetic Group
0      1          1  0.123             A
1      1          2  0.234             A
2      2          1  0.345             C
3      2          2  0.456             C
4      3          1  0.567             A
5      3          2  0.678             A
6      4          1  0.789             B
```

I could use a for: loop but wondered if there as a method using any of the Pandas DataFrame merging or joining operations that would avoid this?  Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index by SubID and then use `join` to get what you want:

```
df1.set_index("SubID", inplace=True)
df2.set_index("Subject Number", inplace=True)
df3 = df1.join(df2, how="left")
```

or, you could use `merge` to accomplish without indexing:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on="SubID", right_on="Subject Number", how="left")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.DataFrame({"SubID":[1,1,2,2], "Condition":[1,2,1,2], "Value":[.123,.234,.345,.456]})

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 
   Condition  SubID  Value
0          1      1  0.123
1          2      1  0.234
2          1      2  0.345
3          2      2  0.456

In [4]: a = a.set_index(["SubID","Condition"]).unstack()

In [5]: b = pd.DataFrame({"Subject Number":[1,2], "Genetic Group":['A','C']})

In [6]: b
Out[6]: 
  Genetic Group  Subject Number
0             A               1
1             C               2

In [7]: b["Condition"] = "Genetic Group"

In [8]: b = b.rename(columns={"Genetic Group":"Value"})

In [9]: b = b.set_index(["Subject Number","Condition"]).unstack()

In [10]: b
Out[10]: 
                       Value
Condition      Genetic Group
Subject Number              
1                          A
2                          C

In [11]: r = a.merge(b, left_index=True, right_index=True)

In [12]: r
Out[12]: 
           Value                Value
Condition      1      2 Genetic Group
SubID                                
1          0.123  0.234             A
2          0.345  0.456             C

In [13]: r = r.unstack()

In [14]: r = r.swaplevel(0,2).sort_index()

In [15]: r
Out[15]: 
SubID  Condition           
1      1              Value    0.123
       2              Value    0.234
       Genetic Group  Value        A
2      1              Value    0.345
       2              Value    0.456
       Genetic Group  Value        C
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim.  I took another look at your response today (now I am in front of my PC again) and it makes sense.  I think this may be useful for other operations I will need to do later so thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @PhilipLawrence I should have added more comments but did not have enough time. Basically, your data is in _narrow_ format. I first convert it to _long_ format where each value type has its own column, then add another column with the categories and then convert it back to the _narrow_ format.